# ReactJS value not being stored in for loop while using inline html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, primereact

i have a small problem with this piece of code (using PrimeReact):

```
    let dropDownOptions = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<this.state.filter_bonus.length;i++){
        var filter_option = this.state.filter_bonus[i];
        dropDownOptions.push(
            <React.Fragment>
            <Dropdown value={filter_option.type.bonus_name} 
                options={this.state.bonus_map} 
                onChange={(e) => this.updateTypeFilterAtIndex(e.value,i)} 
                optionLabel="bonus_name" 
                filter showClear filterBy="bonus_name" 
                placeholder="Select a Bonus" />
            <span>
                <InputNumber value={filter_option.value} 
                onValueChange={(e) => this.updateValueFilterAtIndex(e.value,i)} 
                mode="decimal" showButtons min={0} max={100} />
            </span>    
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

This is suposed to create multiple dropdowns and store the values in a list state variable to be read using it's index. This is the function called when some option is selected.

```
updateTypeFilterAtIndex(val,index){
    let new_arr = [...this.state.filter_bonus];
    console.log(index);
    new_arr[index]['type'] = val;
    this.setState({filter_bonus: new_arr});
}
```

This is the result,

[image]

But the problem here is that, when i select some option for example in the first dropdown, the value "i" in the for loop is 0, although when the onChange gets triggered `(e) => this.updateTypeFilterAtIndex(e.value,i)` the value "i" passed will be 1 instead of 0. So it will be referencing the wrong dropdown.
This happens to all dropdowns, it looks like the value stored in the callback is one iteration ahead. Is this normal or is it a bug on React?
I have checked a bunch of times and all looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. Try using forEach() instead of using a for loop.
Ex:

```
this.state.filter_bonus.forEach((item, index)=>{
...
})
```